# How can I plot output of convolutional layers as a scatter plot? Is it even possible?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, matplotlib, deep-learning

i want to plot and see where the data points lie on any n-dimensional plane after passing through a convolutional layer for the purpose of classification. Is it possible?

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(64, (2, 2), activation='relu', padding='same'), 
                          input_shape=(20,128, 128 ,1))) 

model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))))

model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))
model.add(LSTM(units=64, return_sequences=True))

model.add(TimeDistributed(Reshape((8, 8, 1))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(UpSampling2D((2,2))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(UpSampling2D((2,2))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(UpSampling2D((2,2))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(64, (2,2), activation='relu', padding='same')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(UpSampling2D((2,2))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(1, (3,3), padding='same')))
```

Given above is the model. I want to plot output of LSTM unit. Thank you

Comment: It would be really helpful if you had a better description of what you are trying to plot.

Comment: well, i hope the `model.add(LSTM(units=64, return_sequences=True))` will produce some numerical output. Correct me if im wrong. I need to plot those encoded outputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See below for some nice visualization of an LSTM model trained to recognise sign language:

https://medium.com/asap-report/visualizing-lstm-networks-part-i-f1d3fa6aace7

Here their code repository: https://github.com/asap-report/lstm-visualisation